# Efficient code to determine which of the two numbers are larger

Tags: c++, performance

I have two character arrays (each of many bytes in length; for example each can be 10-12 bytes) and they represent a number in binary format. I want to check if one number is larger than the other. What is the most efficient way to check which of the two is the largest? Are there bitwise operations that one can perform to efficiently determine this?

Comment: How are the bytes laid out? Couldn't you just continually compare the most significant bytes/bits until they're different?

Comment: What did you try? Are you sure you have a performance issue on that particular part of your software?? (I'm guessing most ways of solving it are fast enough).

Comment: Do you mean char arrays like **101010101000101010** ? Give a deatailed example

Comment: yeah these are unsigned integers stored using a block of memory. (I used character arrays to simplify my description.) Importing them to gmp bignum format and then comparing is really expensive. I know it is not expensive in itself (100s of nano seconds) but in my application it will be called tens of billions of times per second. so a more efficient way is preferred.

Comment: I assume the byte order is big endian? What is the word width (32/64bit)?

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example program that we can compile and run which illustrates any problems you're having or questions you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can do is firstly use two pointers to point at the first nonzero byte in both (from the left). If now the two *effective lengths* are different, output the longer one. I mean, let's assume that `first` is 10 bytes and `second` is 12 bytes. Byte 4 (`first[3]`) is the first nonzero byte in `first`, and byte 2 (`second[1]`) is the first nonzero byte in `second`. Now the *effective length* of `first` is 7 bytes, while that of `second` is 11. Clearly, `second` is larger.

Now for equal *effective lengths*. Compare the bytes. If equal, go to the next. Otherwise, the larger byte exists in the larger number and we finish.

You can speed this operation up by comparing register-sized chunks (I mean chunks that fill the whole register), because if both chunks are equal you'll skip a number of comparisons equal to the size of the register in bytes... if they are unequal, you can compare byte-by-byte, or you can even compare half-size by half-size firstly... if equal, skip to the other half. If different, then compare quarter-size by quarter-size, and so on before comparing byte-by-byte (this is analogous to binary search).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a bignum data type. You have 10-12 chars to store 80-96 bit integer values. To make it simple, I'm going to assume unsigned values.

Iterate through both arrays simultaneously comparing elements from each array. Start at the most significant element. As soon as you find one element bigger than the other, you have your answer. For extra speed, do machine word size compares by loop unrolling.

But since you are getting these values over the wire, it seems odd that the bignum class is a bottleneck. Surely the network will be your bottleneck. What's more, a good bignum class will be well optimised. Why would your own code beat it?

Comment: Depends what else is happening. What proportion of your total wall clock time is spent doing this comparison? You will have learnt this when you profiled.

Comment: Well, my major portion of the work in this phase is spent in selecting the numbers. so code is spending about 80% of its time in this function that compares and sums the selected numbers.

Comment: Well, if you want to do it yourself then I can't see any better way than I and the others describe.

Comment: @danglingptr: If the numbers are random, nearly all the time you will get your answer on the first byte, so while you have a "bottleneck", it's probably not where you're guessing. Do you have any calls to memory allocation in this loop?

Comment: @danglingptr: Well, the thing I do in every case is *[this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/)*, which tells me for sure if the main time cost is in I/O, importing, or whatever it is. Then *if* it's importing, find a way to bypass it. Often such a functionality is there to try to make your coding easier, but not necessarily fastest.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to compare them from most to least significant byte:

```
// assuming MSB is at index 0
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(a[i] > b[i]) return a;
    if(b[i] > a[i]) return b;
}
// what to return if they're equal?
return a;
```

This requires them both to have the same size. You can work around this limitation by padding the arrays, or by adding extra checks. I don't know which one will run faster.

You can improve this by treating the arrays of `char` as arrays of `unsigned` (or better, a type with size equal to a machine word) if their size is a multiple of `sizeof(unsigned)`, as that will do comparisons wordwise.

Comment: is that the most efficient way possible? are there bitwise tricks that I can use to get better performance?

Comment: This doesn't account for two arrays different in length (which can be equal actually, or even the longer can represent a smaller number). No assumptions are to be made, the guy is asking for an efficient, practical solution!

Comment: For the second check, use `else if`, instead of `if`.  It is more readable, and good practice.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't find a significant difference. I actually find the aligned ifs more readable. It's subjective anyway.

Comment: [@Nawaz] There's no difference actually, since the first `if` returns from the function if successful. In all cases, if we reach the second `if`, *exactly* two comparisons will be done.

Comment: @nawaz if else if rather than if results in different code being generated then there's a problem with the compiler

Comment: Omar: I don't know what the speed constraints are so I provided what I think is a good solution (and now I documented the assumptions, I don't have the time right now to solve this without them). @danglingptr: I doubt there's a bitwise operation that results in a comparison faster than `>` in general, and I think the way to make it faster is not to work at a smaller granularity, but a bigger one (hence the suggestion to compare words instead of bytes).

Comment: got it. I guess on 64 bit machines I can compare 64 bit integers at once. Thanks all!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why? Do you mean `if else-if` and `if if` are exactly same

Comment: @nawaz they are when you consider the return statements

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as a comment but thought I might add it as an answer. Starting from the most significant byte, loop and compare until the two values are different. The number with the largest value at any iteration is therefore the largest number.

If the values are signed, depending on the encoding (such as 2's complement), the first iteration might have to be a special case.

**EDIT:** You just commented that the numbers are unsigned, therefore it should be fairly simple and you only need to worry about the first part.